# pandas not working

Tags: python, macos, pip

It seems that I already have pandas downloaded but I can't seem to use it in my program

I am using a mac with version 10.12.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated

here is my console commands

```
➜  Downloads cat code.py
import pandas

➜  Downloads pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-    packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)
➜  Downloads python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
➜  Downloads
```

Comment: Did you install `Python3` using **homebrew**? If so, the corresponding `pip` for `Python3` is `pip3` rather than `pip`.

Comment: this is what happened when i tried to install with homebrew:

Comment: If you want to run under Python3 interpreter, you need to run `python3 code.py` or add a shebang at line 1 that says `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`. If you just run `python`, you will run the Apple-supplied Pyython2 interpreter that doesn't know about the modules you installed under **homebrew**.

Comment: still have the same problem:   ➜  Downloads python3 code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
➜  Downloads

Comment: What happens if you run `type python` and `type python3`?

Comment: ➜  Downloads type python
python is /usr/bin/python
➜  Downloads type python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
➜  Downloads

Comment: I would remove any existing `python3` and `pip3`, with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/{pip3,python3}` and then `brew rm python3` and `brew install python3` and then try again. I suspect you have tried a couple of incompatible installations methods and have an unhappy mixture.

Comment: i ran thoughs commands and then tried to get pandas but this happened

Comment: ➜  Downloads pip install pandas
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: no such file or directory
➜  Downloads

Comment: `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: ➜  Downloads pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)

Comment: yet it still doesn't work:   ➜  Downloads python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: `python3 code.py`

Comment: ➜  Downloads python3 code.py
zsh: command not found: python3

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python3 code.py`

Comment: ➜  Downloads /usr/local/bin/python3 code.py
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Try `brew link python3 --force`

Comment: ➜  Downloads brew link python3 --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3...
Error: Could not symlink bin/idle3
Target /usr/local/bin/idle3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/idle3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python3

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python3

Comment: That is good advice, follow it.

Comment: ➜  Downloads rm /usr/local/bin/idle3
➜  Downloads brew link --overwrite python3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3... 23 symlinks created
➜  Downloads brew link --overwrite --dry-run python3
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3
To relink: brew unlink python3 && brew link python3
➜  Downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use **Python3** on a Mac under **homebrew**, you need to:

- install **homebrew**, by going to [the homebrew website](http://brew.sh)
- install **Python3** with

  `brew install python3`
- install any **Python3** packages with `pip3` rather than `pip`:

  `pip3 install PACKAGE       # e.g. pip3 install pandas`

---

If **Python3** is installed correctly under **homebrew**, you will see that `/usr/local/bin/python3` is a symlink to something in **homebrew**'s Cellar:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3

lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin      35  6 Oct 16:13 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.3/bin/python3
```

If that is not the case, you have either not installed **Python3** or you had a previous installation and **homebrew** was reluctant to overwrite it. In which case, if you really want to run with **homebrew**'s **Python3**, run:

```
brew link python3 --force
```

and check again if it is a symlink.

---

Then, when you run any **Python3** scripts, you either need to put the full path in your shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import something
import something-else
```

or, run with:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 some-script.py
```

or, if your PATH includes `/usr/local/bin`:

```
python3 some-script.py
```

You can check your PATH with:

```
echo $PATH
```

and see if it has `/usr/local/bin` near the start - which is what you want if you use **homebrew**.

---

If you have set up correctly, and you run:

```
type python3
```

it will report:

```
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

because **homebrew** installs package binaries into `/usr/local/bin`. If it tells you anything other than `/usr/local/bin/python3`, then your PATH is incorrect and it needs setting both in your current session, with something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

and with a similar command in your login profile for subsequent login sessions - that will be something like `$HOME/.profile`, or `$HOME/.bash_profile` if you use `bash`.

---

In general, if you are running **homebrew**, you should check your system health every now and then with:

```
brew doctor
```

and follow the good doctor's advice - he's pretty good - I trained him ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkSetchell, very helpful, I'm still having troubles with other libraries however, for example i ran pip3 install Pillow then tried to run a programming using pillow and it didn't work

Comment: Glad you are up and running - it is confusing, especially if you start out with a failed installation by some other method. I think we have made a big enough mess of comments on this question so maybe ask a new question for the `pillow` stuff and we can start afresh :-)

Comment: Also i tried brew doctor and got this warning which might be part of the probem

Comment: Ok, i'll make a new question