# Why does brew installed python not see the pip installed modules?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

Both `pandas` and `pandasql` were installed via `pip` and are visible to the system/macos version of `python`. They are not visible to the `brew` installed `python`: they result in

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I have tried the `brew` specific pip's as well:

```
 $/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/libexec/bin/pip install pandasql 
Requirement already satisfied: pandasql in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/sboesch/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pandas->pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Users/sboesch/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas->pandasql)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/sboesch/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas->pandasql)
```

So then why are `pip`/`pip2` and the `brew` version of `python` disagreeing? How can this be fixed?

Note: I have also tried using the `brew` version of `pip` just to be sure: it gives the same results.

```
$which pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/libexec/bin/pip
```

Comment: Brew installs Python to `/usr/local`. Your `pip` clearly refers to the system `/Library/` Python install. They're two different installs.

Comment: @deceze So then *which* `pip` (or derivative such as `pip2`) is used by the `brew` python?  I specifically used `pip` from brew!  `$which pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/libexec/bin/pip`

Comment: `pip2` is different, yes. Run which on **that**

Comment: You might want to just use `python -m pip install` and rely on the Python installation itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46641576/2836621

Comment: @cricket_007  the `pip2` is from brew.   I will try your `python -m`

Comment: @cricket_007  the `python -m` works.  please make that an answer - and maybe add some more details.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I already tried using `pip2` (analogously to your answer in that sof with `pip3`) and as mentioned it gave some results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming brew at least installed Python correctly, a workaround to ensure its pip module is used is to explicitly use it like so

```
python -m pip install
```

If you want, you can alias `pip-inst` to redirect to that, so it's less typing

Comment: While I have accepted and upvoted this answer - would you have any insights into why `pip` were not working properly (even when it is from the `brew` installation under `/usr/local/Cellar/..`) ?

Comment: Try brew doctor? Restart the machine? New terminal session? I'm not sure really